# Message box alert won't stop popping up

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want a message box to pop-up when certain cells are being edited. For example, I have a column for start times and they need to have the format `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS` (in military time). When someone enters the date/time in here I want a message to pop-up that says:

> Use the the following format:  MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS (in military time).

When I try to use the script below the message box keeps popping up over and over, no matter which cell is edited. I would like it to pop-up when the user enters something into that cell, so they know the correct format. I'd like them to be able to hit `OK` and the message disappears, until the next row line with that respective column cell is being edited.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Events");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headerRow = 1;
  var i = 1;
  for (i = 1; i < data.length; i += 1) {
      var row = data[i];
      var startTime = sheet.getRange(headerRow + i, 3).getValue();
          if (row[0] !== "" && startTime !== "") {
              Browser.msgBox('Use the the following format: MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS (in military time)', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
          }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this code completely answers your question.  If not, let me know.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.log('onEdit ran!');

  var columnOfCellEdited = e.range.getColumn(); //Get the column of the cell being edited
  Logger.log('columnOfCellEdited: ' + columnOfCellEdited);

  if (columnOfCellEdited !== 1) {
    return;  //If the user is not editing column one, then quit here
  };

  var valueOfThisCell = e.value; //Only available if the edit is to a single cell
  var rowOfCellEdited = e.range.getRow();

  Logger.log('valueOfThisCell: ' + valueOfThisCell);
  Logger.log('rowOfCellEdited: ' + rowOfCellEdited);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Events");
  var startTime = sheet.getRange(rowOfCellEdited, 3);

  Logger.log('startTime: ' + startTime);

  var formatOfTheDate = 'ToDo get the format';

  if (formatOfTheDate !== "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS") {
     Browser.msgBox('Use the the following format: MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS (in military time)', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  };
}
```

You can use the `e` event object to get information about the current cell being edited.

[Google Documentation - Events for Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events)

Comment: I was wondering, is it possible to format the message box text. For example, are you able to make some of the text bold, italics, etc? I tried it and wasn't successful. It's possible I just didn't do it right.

Comment: Use a custom dialog for custom formatting.  You'll need to use HTML.  [Google Documentation - Custom Dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs)